# shutil.which is evaluating only permanent PATH?

Tags: python, windows

Starting a python script from a cmd shell, where env var `PATH` gots updated for this session (via [`set PATH="<other_location>";%PATH%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1)), let [`shutil.which`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.which) not find the executable.

In contrast when the change of `PATH` is made permanent (via [`setx PATH "<other_location>;%PATH%"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx) or [via gui](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)), `shutil.which` will find it.

Here some sample code to reproduce (python 3.7.9):

run.bat

```bsh
@echo off

setlocal
set PATH="%userprofile%\scoop\apps\postman\current";%PATH%

python which_postman.py
```

which_postman.py

```py
import shutil
import os
from pathlib import Path

print(f"which: {shutil.which('Postman')}")
# stdout: which: None

# check whether command 'Postman' can be resolved
os.system('Postman')
# Launches postman (so PATH will be used by python process)

# check whether shutil.which will find the executable with parameter `path`
for path in os.environ['PATH'].split(';'):
    path = path.strip('"')
    if Path(path).resolve().joinpath('Postman.exe').exists():
        which_incl_path = shutil.which('Postman', path=path)
        print(f"which (including parameter path): {which_incl_path}")
        # which (including parameter path): <userprofile>\scoop\apps\postman\current\Postman.EXE
```

Searching a while I didn't found a similar question or something that explains this behavior. I am not sure whether this is a bug of `which()` or an known behavior that is simply not documented at [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.which) (documentation bug)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I wrote this question, I thought I should provide the python version -- which is some bondary condition in this project. I also tested this with a recent version and found this bug is beeing fixed already. -> *Works in Python 3.9.6*!

Searching in the python changelog, I found this bug (https://bugs.python.org/issue35755) which looks in the comment section like it addresses this issue. **So I assume its fixed since Python 3.8.0 alpha 4**